# "ITMS-90755: Invalid Binary "

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image]

I've been trying to upload a test build using Xcode 15 to TestFlight but keep getting the following error after build is uploaded successfully:

> "Dear Developer,

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "AppName" 1.0.0 (12). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

> ITMS-90755: Invalid Binary - The following binaries in your app contains prohibited instructions: Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App. Remove the instructions from the binaries, rebuild and resubmit.

> Best regards,

> The App Store Team"

What does this error mean? What are those prohibited instructions? Where to fine them in the app binary?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you perhaps submitted an Intel simulator build?